# Access to value from List of component Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, events, components

I make a **Survey Web Page** using **Vue.js 3**

I have **Components** (**InputDate**,**InputText**,**InputNumber**,...)

My Code:

```
 <form-input :comp="dataValue">
      <component
        :ref="d.type"
        :is="d.type"
        v-for="d in dt"
        :key="d.id"
        :id="d.id"
        :title="d.title"
        :required="d.required"
      ></component>
    </form-input>
```

and i have a list :

```
         {
          id: 'dateInput',
          type: 'InputDate',
          error: 'this field is require',
          title: 'Date of Birth',
          required: true,
          errorMessage: 'Please enter correct date',
        },   
        {
          id: 'father',
          type: 'InputText',
          title: 'Father Name',
          error: 'Please Enter Name',       
          ],
        },
        { 
          id: 'familymember',
          type: 'InputNumber',
          title: 'Number of Member',
          error: 'Please Enter correct number',       
          ],
        },
```

**How can get All the value from all the component to execute submit function?**

**Updated:**

I have **submit button** in the **form-input** component to execute submit function

Comment: Sounds like there should just be a single submit button in the form-input component as a sibling to your dynamic component, not inside of it

Comment: Yes, it exists, but I did not put it in the question

Comment: Share your full code then, that is a big piece that you just left out. How are you expecting these individual input components to submit the form? There are many ways to do this but a single submit button inside the form seems the easiest for your case.